Issue with Blender Spiral Curve
I am a beginner at blender/3d modeling and I am trying to create a 3d model of an asian scroll. I've tried my best to draw the issue I'm having with the Blender Archemedian Curve Spiral.

I am trying to replicate the effect of rolling up a scroll. A long piece of paper with wood attached to the end of it. When I roll up my scroll I want the effects of the spiral starting small and gradually growing as it gets more rotations/layers. However, I am having the issue of the spiral starting at max(?) diameter, and proceeding to fill in the inside as it gets more rotations/layers.
First rotation:

Second rotation:

If I try to spiral from the center, I get the intended growing layer look, but experience a clipping error where it cuts through the paper.
First Rotation:

Second Rotation:


I think the main part to get what you want is to make sure the spiral keeps its start radius and the end radius has to grow with the number of rotations.
The width increase has to be a constant value per rotation, not per curve length or anything, so that the distance between each layer stays constant even though the circumference of each layer increases.
To do that, I would animate the value for the rotation, multiply this with the chosen distance and add it to the start radius:

If you now animate the rotation value, the spiral grows outwards while keeping the layer "thickness":

And now to get the illusion as if the core of the spiral was rotating while the spiral is growing, the spiral has to overall rotate, exactly 2*pi or tau (which you can enter directly to get the value) into a Math node set to Multiply which you can then use for Rotation in a Transform Geometry node:

And the result:

So far, so good. To have the endpoint of the spiral at the top of the viewport, I rotate everything 90° on Z with a second Transform Geometry node. I also want the spiral to be "supplied" from somewhere, so I instance a Bézier curve on the endpoint of the spiral. If I set the Start to (0, 0, 0) it will be placed exactly on the spiral's endpoint. I then realize the curve instance to set the position of the outer endpoint to a fixed position so that it doesn't move with the growing spiral.

This is as a basic idea how you could do that. Maybe someone has an even easier method to do it.
You can then convert the curve into a mesh to give it some width as if it was a sheet of paper, put something in the center and give it the same rotation as the spiral so you have something to "hold" the paper. Maybe extrude it for some thickness etc. and in the end it could look something like this:



Thank you very much for the multi step instructions to explain every portion of the animation. This was very informative as a beginner.
